# Run a script for each txt file in all subfolders

Tags: python, recursion, directory

I need to run the following script for each txt file located in all subfolders. 
The main folder is "simulations" in which there are different subfolders (called as "year-month-day"). In each subfolder there is a txt file "diagno.inp". I have to run this script for each "diagno.inp" file in order to have a list with the following data (a row for each day): 
"year-month-day", "W_int", "W_dir"
Here's the code that is working for only a subfolder. Can you help me to create a loop?

```
fid=open('/Users/silviamassaro/weather/simulations/20180105/diagno.inp',  "r")
subfolder="20180105"
n = fid.read().splitlines()[51:]
for element in n:
    "do something" # here code to calculate W_dirand W_int for each day
     print (subfolder, W_int, W_dir)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I usually do when I need to loop over a directory and its child recursively:

```py
import os

main_folder = '/path/to/the/main/folder'
files_to_process = [os.path.join(main_folder, child) for child in os.listdir(main_folder)]

while files_to_process:
    child = files_to_process.pop()
    if os.path.isdir(child):
        files_to_process.extend(os.path.join(child, sub_child) for sub_child in os.listdir(child))
    else:
        # We have a file here, we can do what we want with it
```

It's short, but has pretty strong assumptions:

1. You don't care about the order in which the files are treated.
2. You only have either directories or regular files in the childs of your entry point.

**Edit**: added another possible solution using `glob`, thanks to @jacques-gaudin's comment

This solution has the advantaged that you are sure to get only `.inp` files, but you are still not sure of their order.

```py
import glob

main_folder = '/path/to/the/main/folder'
files_to_process = glob.glob('%s/**/*.inp' % main_folder, recursive=Tre)

for found_file in files_to_process:
    # We have a file here, we can do what we want with it
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why not using `glob`? It does all this for you doesn't it? :)

Answer (score 0):

With [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) you can do something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

sim_folder = Path("path/to/simulations/folder")

for inp_file in sim_folder.rglob('*.inp'):
    subfolder = inp_file.parent.name
    with open(inp_file, 'r') as fid:
        n = fid.read().splitlines()[51:]
    for element in n:
        "do something" # here code to calculate W_dirand W_int for each day
        print (subfolder, W_int, W_dir)
```

Note this is recursively traversing all subfolders to look for `.inp` files.

Comment: Hi! the problem is that my subfolders inside the "simulations" folders need to be changed inside the script because in each different subfolder there's a diagno.inp file on which I have to work..

Comment: I need to enter in each subfolders of "simulations" and open the "diagno.file". In each subfolder there's a "diagno.file" on which I have to work..

Comment: Sure, that's what `rglob` is doing. It goes into all the subfolders recursively and finds any file that match `"*.inp"`. For each match you proceed with your script.